# What voltage is needed to ionize oxygen at the centre of this ball and would we hear any noise from thunder?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics, thermoelectricity

The outer ball is 10 metres in diameter (its surface is the Earth's atmosphere) and a vacuum separates the outer ball from a 1 metre ball of atmospheric air which exists at atmospheric pressure. The oxygen should glow blue.
Electrons should flow from the outer ball surface to the inner ball.
This is a model for balls of light. which form quietly in Hessdalen Norway.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessdalen_lights
http://www.hessdalen.org/index_e.shtml
[image]

Comment: How are the two balls attached? You cannot hear any sounds through a vacuum barrier

Comment: The small ball is floating in the middle held in place by negative charges. When the air is heated it will expand and fill the larger ball.But will there be thunder? Also I have assumed the small ball is kept together by some negative charges  in its middle.

Comment: I do not believe the setup you describe is possible, and to my understanding there were no vacuum conditions in Hessdalen.

Comment: I think you are right.. I was trying to find a way for the lights to form. The vacuum may just be low pressure.  I am wondering if vortexes form in the air and create low pressure that charged ice crystals or water move into.  Or perhaps as negative charge flows to positive charge at high speed a vortex is created. I think the positive charges would have to be at the centre of the vortex. Spirals have been seen in the hot plasma caused by self organising dust particles it is thought.

Comment: The years 2000 to 2009 were 0.2 C colder than 2010 to 2019. and fewer lights were seen from 2010 onwards.
It may be important to note that Hessdalen is at 62 degrees latitude and that a Ferrell weather cell has its boundary with a polar cell at 60 degrees and there is concern that these cells could be changing their boundary positions because of global warming. The Egyptian pharaoh Thutmose 3rd spoke about similar lights and the pyramids are at 30 degrees latitude which is the boundary of a Hadley weather cell and a Ferrell weather cell.

Comment: The Siberian high pressure has been weaker to the east in recent years and perhaps without this cold air less turbulence or ice crystals or moisture have been happening around Hessdalen.